# Able to hide Printer in Guest Account but not User Account in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

I'm able to hide selected printer in Guest account by setting the printer security setting. However, doing the same thing doesn't hide the selected printer from other User account (Standard Type not Admin Type).

May I know if there's anyway to hide specified printer in User Account ( Print Dialog ) ?

Comment: You would be better just setting the printer permissions so that your users can't print to it, rather than trying to hide it...

Comment: @BigChris that would be the last resort if there's no way to hide. It will be great if there's way to hide.